# Ubuntu 16.04 resume after suspend fails in Gnome 3 (but pm-suspend always works)

Tags: gnome, suspend, power-management, gnome-power-manager

Using any suspend action on my Asus Zenbook UX310UA under Gnome 3 always leads to failure to resume. This includes closing the lid or invoking "suspend" at the top right menu.

However, when I type pm-suspend on the command line, suspend/resume always works.

(I read elsewhere that gnome-power-manager no longer uses the pm-suspend scripts --- is there a simple fix I can apply to *force* gnome-power-manager to use pm-suspend?)

This is with latest default kernel 4.4. I tried upgrading to kernel 4.4.8 but that leads to many other problems such as USB and Wifi devices apparently failing, so I prefer a workaround under kernel v4.4 if possible.

Comment: Where did you read about the _gnome-power-manager_.

Comment: I can't find the original reference. But here for example, there is the claim that pm-utils is superseded by systemd:

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/323484/what-do-the-power-management-tools-in-linux-do-acpi-pm-utils-etc